# Hiveserver2 not starting

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have installed Hadoop and Hive on CentOS 5.8. Hadoop is working fine but I am not able to start hiveserver2. Running the command $HIVE_HOME/bin/hiveserver2 gives no output. I have also checked and no process is listening to port 10000 which is the default port. What can be the possible cause?

Comment: Have you checked logs?

Comment: I have the same issue, but safemode is off..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my namenode went into safemode. Turning off safemode fixed the problem.